# Windowing Events

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

Take a table like such:

| ID | KEYID | RECVRID | STAGE | STAGEDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 834 | 3 | 61 | PUBLISHEDDATE | Sunday, November 19, 2023 |
| 834 | 3 | 61 | VIEWEDDATE | Monday, November 20, 2023 |
| 92 | 3 | 61 | PUBLISHEDDATE | Monday, November 20, 2023 |
| 526 | 3 | 61 | PUBLISHEDDATE | Wednesday, November 22, 2023 |
| 526 | 3 | 61 | VIEWEDDATE | Sunday, November 26, 2023 |
| 835 | 3 | 61 | PUBLISHEDDATE | Tuesday, November 28, 2023 |
| 835 | 3 | 61 | VIEWEDDATE | Tuesday, November 30, 2023 |

This is an item (KEYID) going through a series of stages where the date that each stage is hit gets recorded (STAGEDATE). The item always starts with a PUBLISHEDDATE and gets assigned an ID. The item can then move on to one of two paths. In the first path it gets viewed and a VIEWEDDATE is recorded. After the VIEWEDDATE is recorded it gets recycled and is assigned a new ID and new PUBLISHEDDATE. In the second path it never gets viewed and gets recycled which also assigns it a new ID and PUBLISHEDDATE.

What I'm trying to do is build a new column that orders the table by date and assigns a sequential number every time the item is recycled. So, what Id' like to have is:

| ID | KEYID | RECVRID | STAGE | STAGEDATE | HISTORY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 834 | 3 | 61 | PUBLISHEDDATE | Sunday, November 19, 2023 | 1 |
| 834 | 3 | 61 | VIEWEDDATE | Monday, November 20, 2023 | 1 |
| 92 | 3 | 61 | PUBLISHEDDATE | Monday, November 20, 2023 | 2 |
| 526 | 3 | 61 | PUBLISHEDDATE | Wednesday, November 22, 20232 | 3 |
| 526 | 3 | 61 | VIEWEDDATE | Sunday, November 26, 2023 | 3 |
| 835 | 3 | 61 | PUBLISHEDDATE | Tuesday, November 28, 2023 | 4 |
| 835 | 3 | 61 | VIEWEDDATE | Tuesday, November 30, 2023 | 4 |

I've tried doing a DENSE_RANK but I can't rank on ID because there's no guarantee the next ID will be higher than the last.

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY KEYID, RECVRID ORDER BY STAGEDATE) AS HISTORY
```

Comment: I see three issues with your test data. 1) You have two rows for November 20. What rule places the VIEWEDDATE'` before the PUBLISHEDDATE? Why doesn't History increment with the PUBLISHEDDATE on November 22? And why does it increment on November 26? (3) I'm finding it really hard getting **November 31** to load into the database. *Thirty days hath September....*

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I've edited the table and it should make sense now. The two rows for November 20th is valid though. An item can get published then recycled and republished in the same day. It will get a new ID every time it is published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I interpret your corrected data and desired results, what you really want is a new `HISTORY` sequence number for each distinct `ID` value, ordered by the earliest date for that `ID` (`STAGE` can actually be ignored). Different `KEYID` values (not shown in the sample data) would get their own `HISTORY` sequence.

I believe the following will do the trick.

```
SELECT D.*, H.HISTORY
FROM Data D
JOIN (
    SELECT
        KEYID, ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KEYID ORDER BY MIN(STAGEDATE)) AS HISTORY
    FROM Data D
    GROUP BY KEYID, ID
) H ON H.KEYID = D.KEYID AND H.ID = D.ID
ORDER BY STAGEDATE, HISTORY
```

If you really want to focus on just the PUBLISHEDDATE stages, you can add `WHERE STAGE = 'PUBLISHEDDATE'` or change the `MIN(STAGEDATE)` to the *conditional aggregation expression* `MIN(CASE WHEN STAGE = 'PUBLISHEDDATE' THEN STAGEDATE END)`. All variants produce the same results on the current data. Results may be different if an `ID` value exists without a `'PUBLISHEDDATE'` row.

Results:

| ID | KEYID | RECVRID | STAGE | STAGEDATE | HISTORY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 834 | 3 | 61 | PUBLISHEDDATE | 2023-11-19 | 1 |
| 834 | 3 | 61 | VIEWEDDATE | 2023-11-20 | 1 |
| 92 | 3 | 61 | PUBLISHEDDATE | 2023-11-20 | 2 |
| 526 | 3 | 61 | PUBLISHEDDATE | 2023-11-22 | 3 |
| 526 | 3 | 61 | VIEWEDDATE | 2023-11-26 | 3 |
| 835 | 3 | 61 | PUBLISHEDDATE | 2023-11-28 | 4 |
| 835 | 3 | 61 | VIEWEDDATE | 2023-11-30 | 4 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fUTcOlCG).

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution in SQL server by using window function.

```
   select 
        id , 
        keyid , 
        recvid , 
        stage , 
        stagedate ,
        sum(case when stage = 'PUBLISHDATE' then 1 end)
        over(partition by keyid , recvid order by seq , stagedate) as history
    from
        (
            select 
                * , 
                row_number() over(partition by keyid , recvid order by stagedate) as seq 
            from tb_stage
        ) as a;
```